# How to make a link for tabs javascript

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

Hey I can not figure out how to make links for tabs inside the browser that do not change the url location instead it goes into the tab. The way the tabs are changed is using this code:

```
<a href="#tab-1">Tab One</a>
<a href="#tab-2">Tab Two</a>
<a href="#tab-3">Tab Three</a>
```

I wanted to make a javascript call that will enable me to do just that. Here is what I tried but it changes the url locating adding a location. Here is the code:

```
window.location.assign("#tab-3")
```

How can I make my links using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There are many frameworks which support tabs, and it will suit you best to use one of them. Here is a good example: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/.

If you'd like to roll your own, I highly advise this tutorial, which uses only CSS (no JavaScript required!): http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/.

It is best to avoid assigning things to the Window, as this will eat up memory fast and pollutes the so-called 'global scope'. Just in future.

Answer (score 0):

By using Jquery, you can make tabs by playing with CSS `display`. Hiding all while one is visible and set `display:inherit` to show the one the user clicked to.

[Jquery example](http://jsfiddle.net/eBHsZ/)

**HTML**

```
<span id="showtab1">Tab 1</span>
<span id="showtab2">Tab 2</span>
<div id="tab1" class="tab">
    tab1
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab">
    tab2
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#showtab1").click(function(){
        $("#tab1").css("display","inherit");
        $("#tab2").css("display","none");
    });
    $("#showtab2").click(function(){
        $("#tab2").css("display","inherit");
        $("#tab1").css("display","none");
    });
```